# Include/mashup a dynamic wicket page in a static webpage

Tags: wicket, mashup

we have a "static", non-wicket CMS website and we want to include a dynamic wicket page/component in one of the static pages. Our idea was to use jQuery's load() method to load the content. And include wickets ajax js files in the header.

This worked more or less. But to make it work, the base-url of the page had to be redirected to the  ajax endpoint of the wicket server.

Our latest and best solution is to include the page in an iFrame.
Is there any more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a similar thing, but we have made it by using the exact opposite of you. We include html fragment of the static content via Wicket and render our component inside.

Answer (score 1):

I think, including (rich dynamic) Wicket content via ajax call, from static page, can break native Wicket power, action flow in statefull pages.

Opposite strategy (from cedric.gatay) seems better.